# How to set and dropdownlist html tag with alternative selected item

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this class I created to use it for pagination, I am trying to make the dropdownlist for records per page and save the value when it refresh, I did it already in jquery, but I want to learn if can be done without javascript, just for fun, the default value "15" I want to make it dynamic. The property PageSize have the current value of the selected page size for the list, I set that value in the controller.

```
public class SortingPagingInfo
{
    public string SortField { get; set; }
    public string SortDirection { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }

    public SelectList ItemsPerPageList
    { 
      get 
      { return (new SelectList(new[] { "10", "15", "25", "50", "100", "1000" }
            .Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}), 
            "value", "text", "15")); 
      } 
    }
}
```

in the view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Socios";
SortingPagingInfo info = ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo;}    
<td>@Html.DropDownList("ItemsPerPage", info.ItemsPerPageList, new { @id = "ItemsPerPageList" })</td>
@Html.Hidden("PageSize", info.PageSize)
```

I want to change that line for something like @Html.DropDownList("ItemsPerPage", info.ItemsPerPageList, new { @id = "ItemsPerPageList" }, new {@selected = info.PageSize}) I know it is wrong =) just an example.

Then I have this javascript for submiting on dropdown change:

```
$("#ItemsPerPageList").change(function (evt) {
        $("#PageSize").val(evt.target.value);
        evt.preventDefault();
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SortingPagingInfo info)
    {
        ...
        ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo = info;
        return View(persona.ToList());
    }
```

I know I can do this in js (it is working) just with this simple line in page load:

```
$("#ItemsPerPageList").val($("#PageSize").val());
```

SOLUTION to my problem, but not an answer for the question:

What I did was to modify the class to have a private property for page size with a default value, that can be changed later in the view:

```
public class SortingPagingInfo
{
    public string SortField { get; set; }
    public string SortDirection { get; set; }

    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return _pageSize; }
        set { _pageSize = value; }
    }
    private int _pageSize = 15;
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }

    public SelectList ItemsPerPageList
    {
      get          { return (new SelectList(new[] { "10", "15", "25", "50", "100", "1000" }
            .Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}),
            "value", "text", _pageSize)); 
      } 
    }
}
```

Now in the controller actionresult (not the http post one), I can modify the info.PageSize to replace the default one.

Comment: when you create `SelectList` you can set default value to `PageSize` like `return (new SelectList(new[] { "10", "15", "25", "50", "100", "1000" }
            .Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}), 
            "value", "text", PageSize));`

Comment: I thought that, it is a good solution, I made it in a way to set up a default value of 15. (Updated question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post to the actual property on `SortingPageInfo` that holds this value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => info.PageSize, info.ItemsPerPageList, ...)
```

Then the drop down list will automatically select whatever is set for that property. The problem currently is that you're not persisting the selected value through the post in any way.

Comment: The value is persisting, check the javascript, also honestly I don't know how to use lambda expression in a DropDownListFor helper .

Comment: @Gonzalo [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462(v=vs.118).aspx) say: _expression_ - An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display.